# How to add a legend to a plot in ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add legend to this plot using ggplot2?
[image]

I used the following table to make this plot
This is the table:
[image]

I used the following codes to make this plot:

```
## plot the results 
ggplot(MeRe2, aes(x= Years, y=BAU))+
  geom_point(aes(x=Years, y=BAU), colour=("red"))+
  geom_point(aes(x=Years, y=Lw), colour=("orange"))+
  geom_point(aes(x=Years, y=Md), colour=("blue"))+
  geom_point(aes(x=Years, y=High), colour=("green"))+
  geom_line(aes(x=Years, y=BAU), colour="red")+
  geom_line(aes(x=Years, y=Lw), colour="orange")+
  geom_line(aes(x=Years, y=Md), colour="blue")+
  geom_line(aes(x=Years, y=High), colour="green")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = MeRe2$Years)+
  xlab("Years from Now")+ylab(" Total SOC Stocks in BC Soils (TonC/ha)")
```

I need to make a legend on the top right corner of this plot to show what each line means, such as:

SSM

BAU = red line

Low = orange line

Medium=blue line

High = green line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `labs()` function to add the legend title and `scale_color_manual()` function to specify the colors and labels for each line.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(MeRe2, aes(x = Years)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = BAU, color = "BAU")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = LW, color = "Low")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Md, color = "Medium")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = High, color = "High")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = BAU, color = "BAU")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = LW, color = "Low")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Md, color = "Medium")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = High, color = "High")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "SSM",
                     values = c("BAU" = "red", "Low" = "orange", "Medium" = "blue", "High" = "green"),
                     labels = c("BAU", "Low", "Medium", "High")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = MeRe2$Years) +
  xlab("Years from Now") +
  ylab(" Total SOC Stocks in BC Soils (TonC/ha)")
```

[image]